# How to remove the mate terminal icon from the Dash home?

Tags: launcher, unity-dash, mate

I uninstalled Mate, but the terminal is still in dash home. I click on it, and nothing opens. Is there any way I can remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like MATE has been removed but left a `.desktop` file.

Just run this command in a terminal:

```
sudo -H nautilus /usr/share/applications
```

Then find the MATE terminal file with the same name and icon of the one you found in the Dash home and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just run `apt-get autoremove` to remove any extra package:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove mate-core mate-desktop-environment
```

This should remove any package that are related to mate in any way.

Comment: it didn't work help

Comment: In that case you should use purge. Check my updated answer.